# How to create release key for android v2 maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I tried below code for a debug key and its working fine. When i make a apk then map is crashing. After searching in google i found debug key is work in release mode.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

So,how can i create a release key for v2 maps. please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't had the chance of doing that, but for my understanding what should be done is:

**1.** First of all you will need to export you project as a **Signed Application**:

[image]

**Right click your project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package...**

This will take you through wizard where you would have to create a new **release.keystore** with a password or use an existing one you created before.

**2.** From this point on the process should be identical to the one where you use the **debug.keystore**.

**3.** All the steps of creating a debug api key and registering it in `Google API Console` are described at this blog post I wrote:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

**4.** Just remember that using the **debug.keystore** will not give you desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Tyr this..
your directory where you have installed java and go to the bin folder.

**For example-**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_your_version\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\your_user_name\.a
ndroid\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it might help you.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_your_version\bin>keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\(Application).keystore -storepass YOUR_STORE_PASSWORD -keypass KEY_PASSWORD
```

Generally YOUR_STORE_PASSWORD and KEY_PASSWORD are same is "android".